# Object doesn't show in render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

One of my students has designed a light saber and I can't figure out why the lightsaber is not showing up in the cycle render.  Could someone help me out?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6CUhZCXLU7nUHNWUHdNb1R4OVE/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Thank you

Comment: If you're going to downvote a new user's question, I think you should explain why.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason for your downvote is that questions should be as focussed as possible. Explain what you tried and where your problem is. You might like to take a look through the help centre (e.g. http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the object data tab of the saber, set duplication to "None."

[image]

Comment: So, which choice is the right one?

Comment: You usually want "none" for that field