# Child object does not render - even after setting duplication to none

Tags: rendering, animation, parent

I'm having the same problem as this user was ([Object doesn't show in render](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/object-doesnt-show-in-render)), but I have Object Duplication set to none and I have cleared restricted render on my object. But it still does not appear.

It is the child to an armature and when I remove the parent/child relationship the object does render.

Comment: is this in viewport ( render view ) as well as the final render also the render engine you are using ?

Comment: Please add clarity to your question by including screen snapshots of Blender 3D View and the final failed render.

Comment: Besides screen shots, it might be useful if you would post a link to your ~.blend file.

Answer (score 0):

- The location of the armature by design affects the child mesh.  For ease of experience .. have your mesh and armature at the **grid center** at the time of parenting.  Delete [ALL] previous armature modifiers.  They can collect like dust during experimentation.  Inspect carefully your modifiers panel.
- Verify your object is visible in Camera View.  Press [Numpad 0] multiple times to alternate this view.  Objects can be viewed in (Non Camera View) .... yet be off camera in (Camera View) which can cause confusion the first few times.
- Move your object to the center of grid and point the camera to center. Align Active Camera to View.  Control Alt Numpad Zero.
- Place other simple objects near the failed object to make sure your camera has a good view of the entire scene, distance shot ... then refine later.

Comment: These are good habits to follow because after de-parenting anything, the child will jump back to whatever position it started in (or maybe worse, idk) So be sure to move the mesh to the world origin, apply all transforms and/or make sure the registration point is where it should be relative to the origin. This makes everything much simpler.  You might find your mesh if you select it in the Collections panel, hover your cursor over the viewport, and press the "." key on your numpad (if you don't have a numpad, that's the top-left dropdown "View" -> "Frame Selected".