# Object doesn't render in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm trying to design a car and I added a flat cylinder on the hood for the hood ornament.

[image]

**Material display**

[image]

**Rendered display**

Here's what I get when I render the hood:

[image]

The hood ornament isn't showing.

I made sure that the object wasn't ticked off in the Outliner Panel:

[image]

And also made sure that "None" wasn't selected in the "Object" tab of the Properties panel as suggested [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/object-doesnt-show-in-render?s=1%7C1.1614).

[image]

Comment: You might also want to check your render layers.

Comment: I added a blend file with fewer elements to make it lighter, and renamed the object that won't render "won't render"

Comment: Very curious indeed ! I have no idea, however some test reviewed that the object has no problem rendering in Blender internal. I have also tried importing and exporting. I will try fbx format next.... Yah it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You enabled duplication (*Frames*) just click *None* and your object will be rendered.

[image]

Comment: AH! missed that one.