# Object doesn't render - layer conflict?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers

The object on Layer 8 ("Planks") is not rendering, although it is totally visible in **Viewport**.

If I select all the layers together (the desired outcome), then hit **Render**, all the layers will render except this one. If I move the object to one of the other layers, it will still not render.

"**Camera**" is selected in "**Ray visibility**" of the **Object** panel.

When I go back and forth between objects to compare the **Object** panel of the problematic object with the others, I see no difference.

"**Duplication**" is not enabled in the **Object** panel.

In the **Outliner**, all three icons for display in **Viewport**, **Select** and **Render** are selected for the object.

I had the same problem [a few months back](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44380/object-doesnt-render-in-cycles), which was never really resolved because I couldn't share the file because of size issues (same here).

Here are the **Render Layers** settings - there doesn't seem to be a difference from one of the layer in the scene to another:

[image]

I tried to render with two different versions of Blender and found the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you already got it.. the problem is that your backwall has a solidify modifier which is only showing during render..if you dsiable it or move your planks a bit to the front it will work..
hope this helps..

What further confuses about this situation is that the Solidify modifier doesn't show in "Rendered Viewport" mode if the Eye isn't ticked in the modifier settings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is also what the problem was in the other question I linked.

Comment: Glad i could help :)