# Blender object randomly invisible to camera

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

so I spent several hours setting up a scene with exploding glass and for whatever reason the bullet is now invisible to the camera... I've done everything and before you say it no it is not turned off in the outline window.  I am at the end of my whits right now with Blender please someone be my hero.

[image]

Comment: What layers are the target for the bullet?  What layers are the target for the camera?

Comment: Possibly related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33787/why-is-part-of-my-model-not-being-rendered. Check for [render layers](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/post_process/layers.html), whther [dupliframes](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28277/object-doesnt-show-in-render) aren't enabled etc. Post some more screenshots with these settings.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger same layer

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file?

Answer (score 1):

Try appending all your objects to a new file. If it's a glitch it's a glitch and this is what usually saves my day in such situations :-) I've experienced weird behavior with visibility/renderability before...